# Qml/Qt c++: How to automatically update items in Qml ListView when the underlying Qt c++ ListModel changes?

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml

Based on an example video from Qt (the ToDo example), I have created a ListView based Qt/Qml application.

Data for the ListView in Qml comes from a c++ class based on QAbstractListModel. The c++ model class is populated with data from a database.

This all works fine.

I have added a pushbutton in the Qml file which invokes a method in the c++ code that fetches data from a remote source (i.e. makes an https request). The https response data is of course asynchronous with the method that makes the http request.

Debug lines in the c++ https response handler confirm that the response is received okay. I save the response to the database.

If I close the application and re-open it, the new data is shown in the Qml list because, once again, on opening the application the c++ model is populated from the db.

But what I really need is that, after saving the data to the db in the https response handler, I also push the new data to the Qml ListView so that I don't have to restart the application to refresh the updated list data.

Unfortunately I don't know how to push the new data from c++ to Qml. I have tried a number of ways (signals from c++, slots in Qml, reading the updated list from c++, etc) but nothing has worked so far.

I know it has to do with the fact that the pushbutton starts an http request in c++ which is not handled synchronously but in a slot function which is the http response handler.

But unfortunately I don't know how to resolve this issue.

I would appreciate some help with this.

Note:
The following example is in fact off of an excellent YouTube Video on Qt model/view by Mitch Curtis [Using C++ Models in QML - To-Do List](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BcAYDlpuT8)!

But my code is very similar except that I want to add a button which changes the descriptions based on an https response:

```
The c++ files providing the listdata: 
todolist.h and todolist.cpp
=============================================================


#ifndef TODOLIST_H
#define TODOLIST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QVector>

struct ToDoItem
{
    bool done;
    QString description;
};

class ToDoList : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ToDoList(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QVector<ToDoItem> items() const;

    bool setItemAt(int index, const ToDoItem &item);

signals:
    void preItemAppended();
    void postItemAppended();

    void preItemRemoved(int index);
    void postItemRemoved();

public slots:
    void appendItem();
    void removeCompletedItems();

private:
    QVector<ToDoItem> m_Items;
};
=======================================================================
#include "todolist.h"

ToDoList::ToDoList(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_Items.append({ true, QStringLiteral("Wash the car") });
    m_Items.append({ false, QStringLiteral("Fix the sink") });
    m_Items.append({ true, QStringLiteral("Wash the dishes") });
}

QVector<ToDoItem> ToDoList::items() const
{
    return m_Items;
}

bool ToDoList::setItemAt(int index, const ToDoItem &item)
{
    if (index <0 || index >= m_Items.size()) {
        return false;
    }

    const ToDoItem &oldItem = m_Items.at(index);
    bool nothingChanged = oldItem.done == item.done
                            && oldItem.description == item.description;
    if(nothingChanged) {
        return false;
    }

    m_Items[index] = item;
    return true;
}

void ToDoList::appendItem()
{
    emit preItemAppended();

    ToDoItem item;
    item.done = false;
    m_Items.append(item);

    emit postItemAppended();

}

void ToDoList::removeCompletedItems()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_Items.size();) {
        if(!m_Items[i].done) {
            ++i;
            continue;
        }
        //otherwise...
        emit preItemRemoved(i);

        m_Items.removeAt(i);

        emit postItemRemoved();
    }
}


###################################################################

The c++ files implementing the listmodel: 
todomodel.h and todomodel.cpp
==================================================

#ifndef TODOMODEL_H
#define TODOMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractListModel>

class ToDoList;

class TodoModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(ToDoList *list READ list WRITE setList)

public:
    explicit TodoModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    enum {
        DoneRole = Qt::UserRole,
        DescriptionRole
    };

    // Basic functionality:
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

    // Editable:
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value,
                 int role = Qt::EditRole) override;

    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) const override;

    virtual QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;

    ToDoList *list() const;
    void setList(ToDoList *newList);

private:
    ToDoList *m_List;
};

#endif // TODOMODEL_H


===================================================================


#include "todomodel.h"
#include "todolist.h"

TodoModel::TodoModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent)
    , m_List(nullptr)
{
}

int TodoModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    // For list models only the root node (an invalid parent) should return the list's size. For all
    // other (valid) parents, rowCount() should return 0 so that it does not become a tree model.
    if (parent.isValid() || !m_List)
        return 0;

    return m_List->items().size();
}

QVariant TodoModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid() || !m_List)
        return QVariant();

    const ToDoItem item = m_List->items().at(index.row());
    switch (role) {
    case DoneRole:
       return QVariant(item.done);

    case DescriptionRole:
       return QVariant(item.description);
    }

    return QVariant();
}

bool TodoModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (!m_List) {
        return false;
    }

    ToDoItem item = m_List->items().at(index.row());
    switch (role) {
    case DoneRole:
       item.done = value.toBool();
        break;
    case DescriptionRole:
       item.description = value.toByteArray();
        break;
    }

    if (m_List->setItemAt(index.row(), item)) {
        emit dataChanged(index, index, QVector<int>() << role);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

Qt::ItemFlags TodoModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return Qt::NoItemFlags;

    return Qt::ItemIsEditable;
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> TodoModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> names;
    names[DoneRole] = "done";
    names[DescriptionRole] = "description";

    return names;
}

ToDoList *TodoModel::list() const
{
    return m_List;
}

void TodoModel::setList(ToDoList *newList)
{
    beginResetModel();

    if(m_List) {
        m_List->disconnect();
    }

    m_List = newList;

    if(!m_List) {
        endResetModel();
        return;
    }

    connect(m_List, &ToDoList::preItemAppended, this, [=]() {
        const int index = m_List->items().size();
        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), index, index);
    });
    connect(m_List, &ToDoList::postItemAppended, this, [=]() {
        endInsertRows();
    });

    connect(m_List, &ToDoList::preItemRemoved, this, [=](int index) {
        beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), index, index);
    });
    connect(m_List, &ToDoList::postItemRemoved, this, [=]() {
        endRemoveRows();
    });

    endResetModel();
}
#########################################################################

The View File: ToDoList.qml
Displays the data provided by the c++ classes
============================================

import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

import ToDo 1.0

ColumnLayout {
    Frame {
        Layout.fillWidth: true

        ListView {
            implicitWidth: 250
            implicitHeight: 250
            clip: true
            anchors.fill: parent

            model: TodoModel {
                list: toDoList
            }

            delegate: RowLayout {
                width: parent.width

                CheckBox {
                    checked: model.done
                    onClicked: model.done=checked
                }
                TextField {
                    text: model.description
                    onEditingFinished: model.desciption = text
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                }
            }
        }

    }

    RowLayout {
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Add new item")
            onClicked: toDoList.appendItem()
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        Button {
            text: qsTr("Remove Completed Items")
            onClicked: toDoList.removeCompletedItems()
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The answer here depends on how you've implemented your `ListView`'s model (and the elements it contains). Could you share some example code that shows the `ListView`, its `ListModel`, and the elements that get added to that `ListModel`? Would also be good to see how the https response handler is exposed to the `Item` containing the `ListView`.

Comment: @dabbler, I have added the code based on which I created my application. Any good now?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the Model changes we should notify the View. Refer to this [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qabstractitemmodel-subclass):

> QML views are automatically updated when the model changes. Remember
> the model must follow the standard rules for model changes and notify
> the view when the model has changed by using
> QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged(),
> QAbstractItemModel::beginInsertRows(), and so on. See the Model
> subclassing reference for more information.

Here's how you can enhance your example to achieve a similar result:
On click of `Fetch data` button, after 3 seconds, the first row's description changes to `https`.

todolist.h:

```
signals:
    void updateData();
public slots:
    void fetchData();
```

todolist.cpp:

```
void ToDoList::fetchData()
{
    QTimer::singleShot(3000, (QObject*)this, SIGNAL(updateData()));
}
```

todomodel.cpp:

```
connect(mList, &ToDoList::postItemRemoved, this, [=]() {
    endRemoveRows();
});

connect(mList, &ToDoList::updateData, this, [=]() {
    QVariant value = "https";
    QModelIndex index = createIndex(0,0);
    setData(index, value, DescriptionRole);
});
```

ToDoList.qml:

```
Button {
    text: qsTr("Remove completed")
    onClicked: toDoList.removeCompletedItems()
    Layout.fillWidth: true
}
Button {
    text: qsTr("Fetch data")
    onClicked: toDoList.fetchData()
    Layout.fillWidth: true
}
```

Comment: I will try your solution and will update this post. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it to work not by copying your code but by picking up a tip or two. The most useful thing for me was this line from your answer ```QModelIndex index = createIndex(0,0);``` I simply di not know how about createIndex(). Thanks again buddy!

Answer (score 0):

I have now fixed my issue thanks to @ArunKumarB.
The main tip from @ArunKumarB's comment was `QModelIndex index = createIndex(0,0);`
That is, how to convert a row index to a QModelIndex object.
The rest was mostly plumbing.

Comment: Nicely done. You should upvote their answer and accept it.

Comment: @dabbler, I wish I could. Apparently, I need 15 reputations.
If you can, please upvote the answer on my behalf.
Kindly upvote the question too :)

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that was limited... Seems silly.